# VCL TSpeedButton doesn't change font size in Delphi 10.4.1

Tags: button, font-size, delphi-10.4-sydney

I have just upgraded from Delphi 10.3 to Delphi 10.4.1 and I have tried to upgrade couple of applications. It seems they worked fine except for one thing.

TSpeedButton refuse to change font size and it always shows default size of 8.

To demonstrate the problem I have made a new VCL TForm, with one TButton, one TBitBtn and one TSpeedButton (left picture), then I have changed Font.Size of the TForm to 11. TSpeedButton ignores that (middle picture). Then I have changed Font.Size of TSpeedButton to 20. TSpeedButton ignores that too (right picture).

[image: TSpeedButton font size bug]

ParentFont of the TSpeedButton was true on the middle picture, and Font.Size of the TSpeedButton was displayed correctly as 11.

Any ideas what to do?

Comment: same problem, are you solved this problem .

Comment: No, I think solving that would be wasting of time: You have three options:
(1) replace SpeedButtons with Buttons or BitButtons;
(2) wait till Embarcadero issue updated Delphi with no bug;
(3) waste time trying to fix thing that shoudn't never be broken.

I have chosen the second options.

Comment: And the long waiting is over, BitBtn has been fixed :-)

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug in Delphi 10.4.1: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-30755

It is supposed to be fixed in 10.4.2.